# Using the secdot package, display dots also in the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

My requirement for section numbering is as follows:

```
1. Section foo
1.1 Subsection foobar
1.1.1 Sub-subsection barfoo
2. Section bar
etc.
```

The important thing is the dot after the section numbering, but not after any lower level section. By just including `\usepackage{secdot}` in the preamble, I am able to achieve what I want **in the main document, but not in the table of contents**.

Even though there are several very similar questions on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com), I wasn't able to find any solution addressing my exact problem. The package documentation for the `secdot` package doesn't contain a command for manipulating the ToC, either.

A MWE, as requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{secdot}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{TestSection}
\subsection{TestSubSection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer a starter document that is compilable

Comment: As the only really important command is stated in my text, I thought it would not be of any use, but there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `secdot` documenation sparse is understatement. In fact, there's no clue from the package documentation. Perhaps looking into the package itself might help...

... but `tocloft` usage is easier, for the quick work - around:

`tocloft` grants access to the slot after the section number, this is called `\cftsecaftersnum` (after section number) for the section number, similarly `\cftsubsecaftersnum` and `\cftsubsubsecaftersnum`. Those must be redefined to have the `.` (dot).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{secdot}

\sectiondot{section}
%\sectiondot{subsection}
%\sectiondot{subsubsection}

\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
%\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnum}{.}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Subfoo}
\subsubsection{Subsubfoo}

\section{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants `\cftsubsecaftersnum` and `\cfrsubsubsecaftersnum` to be empty, while `\cftsecaftersnum` is `.`.

Comment: @MickG: True, but that's easy to achieve